# MVVM approach, what's a good way? How to improve/speed up development?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, design-patterns, mvvm

this post is meant to have a list of suggestions on MVVM approach... What tools do you use, what do you do to speed up development, how do you maintain your application, any special ways of finding defects in this design pattern......

here is what I do:

So first i create my model/db with EF.

Then I create Views (either user controls or windows) with their respective viewmodel. I usually place the viewmodel in the same location as my view. But while starting the name of my view with "UC-name", I call my viewmodel just "name-model".

In my viewmodel I implement InotifyPropertyChanged

in my xaml view I have a resource of my viewmodel, and bind my grids/controls via the itemsource to the staticresource.

I try to do a lot of front end logic with triggers and styles and also place some code in the xaml.cs file if it regards logic for behaviour of my controls.

I can reach my viewmodel from my view (xaml + xaml.cs).

for communiation between viewmodels I use MVVM lights.

that's pretty much it.

---

Things I'm thinking about

- I'm thinking of using T4 templates for generating viewmodel/view. What do you guys think of this. is this worth it?
- when using MVVM light Messenger, we get a subscription based communication, and sometimes I find it hard to track what has changed in my DataContext. Any suggestions on this?
- any other improvements or suggestions are more than welcome !

Comment: As a suggestion: I would look on popular MVVM Frameworks like Caliburn Micro or the others listed here:
https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/MVVM+framework+comparison+sheet

Comment: Just a humble opinion. When I first started developing WPF I didn't know about MVVM. My partner and I basically create a framework from the ground. When we saw someone using MVVM our jaws dropped. Now I don't think that WPF can "exist" without it. Another humble opinion. Don't rely too much on Toolkits. We didn't use any and we were doing pretty well!

Comment: I really do enjoy productivity tools though, just like : http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/mvvm/

Comment: I just checked out Caliburn micro and also MVVM light, I like Caliburn micro because it requires a lot less code, but fact that it basis it self on so much convention makes it hard to reverse engineer when someone is new to a project. In this case I would prefer configuration with code generation to speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

Answering first question regarding `View/ViewModel` generation I think for CRUD cases it makes sense to use some tools, otherwise it won't be that beneficial.

Pretty nice basic scaffolding implementation example you can find here: [WPF CRUD Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36975/WPF-CRUD-Generator-Scaffolding). Also [WPF solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILWdnTsIDfc) by **DevExpress** looks really promising.

There are at least couple **Codeplex** projects addressing `View/ViewModel` generation:

- [WPF Scaffolder](http://wpfscaffolder.codeplex.com/)
- [ViewModel Tool by Clarius](http://clarius.codeplex.com/clarius/wikipage?title=ViewModel%20Tool&referringTitle=Home)

But I am quite pessimistic about **T4** for such scenarios. I think writing and polishing own T4's will take you much more time than adoption of existing tools.

---

Regarding *MVVMLight* messenger I can say that it will take you some time to get used to it. And as soon as you will understand difference between "regular" and message driven *MVVM* you'll be able to use it in most efficient way. Very nice article about messenger is [Messenger and View Services in MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx).
 And want to add a really important quote from there:

> **A Word of Caution About Messenger**
>
> Messenger is a powerful component that can greatly facilitate the task
>   of communication, but it also makes the code more difficult to debug
>   because it is not always clear at first sight which objects are
>   receiving a message. Use with care!

Answer (score 1):

I'm very much a proponent of Domain-Driven Development (DDD). First I have the designer write specifications, roughly adhering to the methodologies in Behavior-Driven Development (BDD). This then forms the basis of unit tests for Test-Driven Development (TDD), for which I use NUnit. For the domain layer itself I start with an Anemic Domain Model i.e. entity classes containing mostly properties and virtually no methods; there are plenty of arguments both for and against this but personally I find it works well. Coupled with this is the Business Logic Layer (BLL) which knows only about the domain entities.

For the Data Access Layer (DAL) I prefer NHibernate, it supports all the usual things you would expect like lazy loading and repository management etc but particularly important is the Object Relational Mapping (ORM) i.e. the bit that translates between your domain entities and the underlying database representation.

One of the problems with NHibernate, in my opinion, is that it uses XML files to do the mapping for the ORM. This means two things: first is that any errors you introduce won't get picked up until run-time. Secondly it's not really a proper "solution" to ORM at all, instead of writing mapping classes you just wind up writing XML files. Both of these problems can be solved by using Fluent. Fluent solves the first problem by replacing XML files with C# files, so your mapping declarations are now done in code which will usually pick up errors at compile-time. It solves the second problem by providing an auto-mapper, which looks at your entities and generates the necessary mapping files automatically. This can be manually overridden if and where needed, although in practice I find I seldom need to. Since the auto-mapper uses reflection is does tend to be a bit slow but it can be run in an offline utility and then saved to a configuration file that is loaded at run-time for near-instant start-up; the same utility can also be used to create your database automatically. I've used this tech with MySql, MS Server and MS Server CE...they've all worked fine.

On the other side of the tier is your view model. I've seen a lot of projects create an almost 1:1 mapping of domain entities to view model classes, I may infuriate MVVM purists by saying this but I really don't see the point in doing all that extra work for something that isn't really needed. NHibernate allows you to provide proxies for the classes it creates, using Castle Dynamic Proxy you can set an intercepter to your NHibernate session factory that automatically injects INotifyPropertyChanged notification to all of your entity properties so that they work with the WPF binding mechanism. Another product, uNhAddIns, allows you to replace any lists with an ObservableCollection in order to get INotifyCollectionChanged support (for reasons I won't go into you can't just put an ObservableCollection into your entities without it seriously affecting performance).

If you're designing and building your application properly using technologies like these and fully unit-testing along the way then you're going to need some way of handling Inversion of Control (IoC) so that you aren't passing object references around all over the place, and for that you'll need a dependency injection framework. My personal preference is Ninject but Unity is pretty good too. Dependency injection is particularly important for good database session management (so that all relevant objects reference the same session), a good rule is one session per WPF form or one per web request.

There are lots of other little things I use to make life easier (MVVM Lite, log4net, Moq for mocking objects for unit testing etc) but this is my core architecture. It takes a while to set up but once you've got it all going you can build fully functional database applications in literally minutes without any of the headaches traditionally associated with layer management in tiered enterprise applications...you just create your domain entities and then start coding for them. Your schema is created automatically, your database is created automatically, you can use your entity classes to fill your database for immediate stress testing and you have full WPF support without having to pollute your entity classes with code or attributes not actually related to the domain. And since all development is driven by anemic domain entities your data is already in the perfect format for serialization into html/ajax/soap etc when you want to give your app web capablities.

You'll notice that I haven't discussed the presentation/XAML layer, mainly because that part is now straightforward. Using a decent architecture you can actually create a fully working and tested application that then only needs pure XAML added to turn it into a releasable product.